# Can't pass parameter to child component Reactjs -> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to access a detail component that should get the props from the main component.
I set the routes and params, and the app redirects to the detail page.
Despite of that, I receive the error `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component`.

What do I have to do to solve this?

**App.js**
[App Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/marcelosdm/039ceb469e1c8a25c42c6d75c5602dfd)

**Main.js**

[Main.js Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/marcelosdm/d391925d52bb7ee437801ee443cc06f9)

**Hero.js**
[Hero.js Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/marcelosdm/b8ab0719a86b1e8147f200f88a904127)

Comment: What's it rendered by the Main.js?

Comment: What is `loadHeroes()`? Does this do an async fetch?

Comment: @Girgetto sorry... I couldn't upload the whole file here, so I edited the post and left a link to a Github gist...
Here it goes:
https://gist.github.com/marcelosdm/d391925d52bb7ee437801ee443cc06f9

Comment: @JosephD. I'm sorry, I couldn't upload the whole file here... answering your question: Yes! 
See the whole code here: https://gist.github.com/marcelosdm/d391925d52bb7ee437801ee443cc06f9

Comment: Hi Marcelo, instead of posting your code as images, can you please include it as text in your question? Using images means we can't copy and paste into IDEs, or copy and paste relevant sections into our answers.

Comment: @CalIrvine I'm sorry, and thank you for the tip! I tried to copy the whole code, but I got the Stackoverflow error that my question was mostly code... 
Anyway, I've just edited this post and put those links to those Github Gists